# A list of functions? And what good is it for?

Tags: r

In this piece of code, it uses list as what appears to be a function to capture functions created upstream of it. Not entirely sure what good is it for nor how each of the pieces fit together. Can someone clarify what this is doing.

" Assignment: Caching the Inverse of a Matrix 
Matrix inversion is usually a costly computation and there may be some benefit to caching the inverse of a matrix rather than compute it repeatedly (there are also alternatives to matrix inversion that we will not discuss here). Your assignment is to write a pair of functions that cache the inverse of a matrix.

Write the following functions:

makeCacheMatrix: This function creates a special "matrix" object that can cache its inverse.  "

```
makeCacheMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
  j <- NULL
  set <- function(y){
  x <<- y
  j <<- NULL
  }
  get <- function()x
  setInverse <- function(inverse) j <<- inverse
  getInverse <- function() j 

  list(set = set, get = get,        #list of functions
  setInverse = setInverse, 
  getInverse = getInverse)
}
```

Comment: This is somebody using lists as an OOP system. This is not code to be emulated, which is given away by the `<<-`s.

Comment: @alistaire This is a classic example used to demonstrate lexical scoping and actually illustrates valid use of <<-.

Comment: Try `demo(scoping)` for another example of this.

Answer (score 0):

The functions `set`, `get`, `setInverse` and `getInverse` are all created locally in `makeCacheMatrix`, and then returned in the list result of that function.  What this does is give them access to the local variables in `makeCacheMatrix`:  the argument `x`, and the value `j`.  (They'll also have access to each other, but they don't use that.)

The `<<-` assignments in some of those functions don't make local assignments, they assign in the captured environment that holds the local variables.

This is a way to have persistent values in those functions.  As a commenter said, it's similar to what many OOP systems do via objects and classes, but the object is somewhat invisible here.  You would need to use something like `environment(result$set)` to get access to it, assuming you had just run

```
result <- makeCacheMatrix(M)
```

Another difference from most OOP systems is that there is no shared class definition or inheritance at all.